# Modifying an existing Module : ComponentPresentationDeploy

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, deployer, extension-model

Online Docs Reference [HERE](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US&docid=GUID-894AB0F0-313C-45A3-B8FC-8A02DA894C93&query=%2Bcomponentpresentationdeploy#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-9EBB3F71-3E3C-40E1-A278-03BAF3086EBF.xml&docid=GUID-9EBB3F71-3E3C-40E1-A278-03BAF3086EBF&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-9EBB3F71-3E3C-40E1-A278-03BAF3086EBF)

While extending a deployer, here `ComponentPresentationDeploy` , as seen below, Where are the different functions, classes documented ?

```
protected void processComponentPresentation(ComponentPresentation cp, File cpfile) {

    TCMURI id = cp.getComponentKey().getId();
    ItemDAO dao = (ItemDAO) StorageManagerFactory.getDefaultDAO("ComponentMeta");
    ComponentMeta compMeta = (ComponentMeta) dao.findByPrimaryKey(id.getPublicationId(), id.getItemId());  
    Integer schemaId = compMeta.getSchemaId();
}
```

for example: `ItemDAO`, `ComponentMeta`, `StorageManagerFactory` etc...

I needed to get the TCM URI and read the MetaData field values of the published component ,done as above, however need full members,properties,functions details of the above classes used.

Searched through onlineDocs, CHMs. So far some google searches helped understand a little bit here.

Comment: The javadoc should be available as a download too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [downloads page](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-2301148A-E3EA-43EF-A2FC-7D3C9BAEE8FF) of [docs.sdl.com](http://docs.sdl.com/) you can find all the javadoc for Content Delivery, and there you should find all the methods you're searching for.

As it seems like you've found it... the easiest way seems indeed to be to "take a look behind the curtain" to figure out how Tridion does it itself, and probably looking online for other examples of deployer extensions, like [this one](https://community.sdl.com/developers/tridion_developer/b/weblog/archive/2011/09/06/deployer-extensions-with-eclipse-step-1-introduction-concepts-amp-requirements).

Comment: Thanks Nuno. Right from being a Newbie in Tridion to moving on to new advance level development now in tridion, you guys here always helped a lot.  The only challenge mostly I face is regarding a proper guide/tutorial on  the concepts, details on existing classes, functions  and namespaces available ( as mostly we see in any book e.g. on .Net :)  ). After that I was able to fully implement/code, use classes, functions as per my own requirements. The Java Docs helped a lot as they contain full details on  various classes available. Thanks once again.